# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null Error in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, xampp, java-server

**Index.jsp:**

```
<form action="stu_app_serv" method="post">
                    <table class="table">                    
                        <%
                            try {
                                String sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE approved = ?";
                                Connection conn = DBConnect.connect();
                                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                                pstmt.setInt(1, 0);
                                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                                while (rs.next()) {
                        %>                    
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input disabled name="id" value="<%=rs.getInt("st_id")%>"></td>
                                <td><%=rs.getString("name")%></td>
                                <td><%=rs.getString("university")%></td>
                                <td><%=rs.getString("index_no")%></td>
                                <td><%=rs.getString("email")%></td>
                                <td>

                                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="approve">Approve </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="decline">Decline</button>

                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>                  
                        <%}
                                rs.close();
                                pstmt.close();
                                conn.close();
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        %>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

Servlet file is **stu_app_serv.java:**

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
int x = Integer.parseInt(id);
```

st_id is the Student ID number. There shows the following runtime error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

in servlet line

> int x = Integer.parseInt(id);

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are you passing an `id` to the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle Null value and put inside try catch block. One thing don't do business logic in presentation layer. As you're here writing the code in jsp rather do in your service class or servlet.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");

    int x = 0;
    if(id!=null){
      try{
        x = Integer.parseInt(id);
       }catch(Exception e){
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether id is not null first, and it must be a valid number. you can use Regex to check that or catch that exception..

Answer (score 0):

When creating this simple program:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
    String id  = null;  
    int x = Integer.parseInt(id);
   }
```

you can see that you will get a NPE.

So it can be assumed the `id` that you are sending is null.